# How to compare 3 fields that are not equal?

Tags: sql, oracle

New to sql..

Looking for the best way to compare 3 fields that contain the same value. If field1= field2= field3 do not display data. Something like what is below, but I receive an error when using this syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM [Customers]
where customername <> name <> name2
```

Comment: What flavor of SQL? What error are you getting?

Comment: The error is  The SQL Statement is invalid: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: `[Customers]` is an invalid identifier in SQL, remove the `[ .. ]`

Comment: I believe it's valid in sql-server

Comment: @DBug: it's valid T-SQL, but not valid in SQL (as in "standard SQL"). And no other DBMS (except for Sybase which shares the same roots) supports that non-standard syntax

Comment: It is a hosted software using SQL Server 2012

Comment: No, it can't be SQL Server if you get an error message that starts with `ORA-`

Comment: This was just an example.. It is part of a very long query..

Comment: Your question is pretty highly in the region of 'Opinion-based'. Please explain what do you mean by "best" so that community members can provide you useful answers.

Comment: By best, I mean the most efficient way to compare these 3 fields.  To produce results where A = B =C and the data does not display.

Answer (score 2):

In general, have to list each comparison separately, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM [Customers] where customername <> name and customername <> name2 and name <> name2
```

Comment: The issue I am running into with this is I am eliminating all results where customername <> name AND customername <> name2 AND name <> name2.  I only need to eliminate results where customername and name and name2 are all equal values?

Comment: Guess we have to change the logic.  Could write it as:  `where not (customername = name and customername = name2 and name = name2)`

Answer (score 2):

In any dialect of SQL, I would want to be careful with `NULL` values with this construct.  It is temping to write:

```
where customername <> name and customername <> name2 and name <> name2
```

This will always filter out rows if any of the values are `NULL`.  If you want `NULL` to be ignored, then you need more complex logic.  Perhaps:

```
where (customername <> name or customername is null or name is null) and 
      (customername <> name2 or customername is null or name2 is null and
      (name <> name2 or name is null or name2 is null)
```

This may or may not be what you want.  I just want to point out that `NULL` values are filtered by out in your logic, regardless of whether any of the comparisons are true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick,

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN  A NOT IN (SELECT B FROM T 
                            UNION ALL 
                            SELECT C FROM T
                           ) ) A From T
```